# Tensorflow.js error: must be either an HTMLVideoElement but was HTMLVideoElement

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting this error in the console using tensorflow.js

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels()
> must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement,
> HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData
> in webworker or {data: Uint32Array, width: number, height: number},
> but was HTMLVideoElement

I am just passing a video html element after it's loaded so what does it mean?

My js code code:

```
...
const input_tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(document.getElementById("video"));
```

My html tag:

```
<video id="video" autoplay muted></video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work by opening a issue in the [tfjs repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4189)

I copy here the solution provided by the github user tafsiri

> After digging around a bit, it looks like your project is running in
> separate context mode and there are two JS contexts in which code is
> run. Your code is being run in the browser context and the tfjs
> library code is being run in the node context. In the node context
> video instanceof HTMLVideoElement returns false. The nw.js docs
> suggest that browser api's aren't usable in the node context so there
> may be incompatibility there.
>
> Their docs suggest you can switch to mixed context mode, I tried that
> by adding the following entry to the package.json and then it worked.
>
> `"chromium-args": "--mixed-context"`, If you want to stay in separate
> context mode (and I don't know enough about nw.js to know the
> advantages and disadvantages of each) you would need to not use any of
> the browser specific apis of tfjs.